# 2 Separate API Keys for 1 Web Service?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

I'm using the Google Places API. It looks like I need to URL's though. One for the "Place Search" and another one for "Place Details". My API key has worked fine for "Place Search", but when I try to use the same key for the second request, I get a message saying "Error access denied." Here are the links for the API:

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search   <-- Place Search

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details  <-- Place Details

I don't understand, because they should just be 1 API? Also, these services are technically connected, so I don't see why I would need 2 separate keys?

Also, here is the code where I am using the key:

```
 NSString *placeURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=%@key=%@", placeId, kGOOGLE_API_KEY];
```

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance